# Android ColorPicker Dialog - Chang theme

Tags: android, colors, dialog, picker

I'm using the ColorPicker Dialog the which is contained in the API Demos (SDK Android)... When I use it on my app, the size is changed, also the background color... How can I get the same Dialog as in the API demo, here are both pictures:

This is what I like to get
[image]

And this is what I'm getting
[image]

Comment: the reason it looks like that is because you set a title on your dialog. remove that and you will get it the same

Comment: Removing the title just quit the text, but the dialog don't changes, it seems equal

Comment: post your xml of the view

Comment: I found that using the @android:style/Theme.WithActionBar Theme it seems like I want... But I dont like the theme for all the view, just for the Dialog... How can I do it??

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer? Please post. Thanks

Comment: Correct answer has been marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, just change the constructor of the ColorPickerDialog:

```
public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                         OnColorChangedListener listener,
                         int initialColor) {
     super(context,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar);//set you favorite theme
     //super(context); //This is the normal constructor


    mListener = listener;
    mInitialColor = initialColor;
}
```